# Destructor throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I've unit tests in which I'm setting a property on a resource in a destructor of a class as true but it's throwing null reference excpetion. the resource is provided to the class and still has reference to the caller.

Unit Tests are passing but I see NullReferenceException in the console and the line number points to the line in the destructor.

```
class Resource
{
    public bool Release { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Class being test

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        Resource.Release = true; // error points to this line
    }

    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

Unit Test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestRelease()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Resource resource = new Resource();
        foo.Resource = resource;

        Assert.IsTrue(resource.Release == false, "Expecting resource.Release == false");

        foo = null;
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Assert.IsNotNull(resource, "Expecting resource is not null");
        Assert.IsTrue(resource.Release == true, " Expecting resource.Release == true");

    }
```

**Error**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Foo.Finalize()
```

**Edit** - this fixes the issue but don't know why?

Interestingly I added this line and now no more errors. else clause never gets called meaning destructor/finalize is only called once, but question still remains there, why it threw error in the first place without if?

```
    ~Foo()
    {
        if(Resource != null)
        {
            Console.Write("releasing");
            resource.Release = true;
        } else
        {
            Console.Write("this never gets executed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: They're called **Finalizers**, not Destructors. Finalizers should be used with unmanaged resources. Neither `Resource` nor `Foo` appear to be unmanaged. Finalizers are indeterminant and perhaps that is causing your issue.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, what's the difference between managed and unmanaged resources, also what can I do to fix the code?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - I prefer the term finalizer too, but unfortunately the [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) disagrees on the terminology.

Comment: Managed is pretty much anything in the framework. Unmanaged is things like files, raw memory, items returned from p/invoke. Google unmanaged vs managed. Finalizers despite their syntax are not like c++ Destructors. They don't run when they go out of scope. Instead they are put in the finalization queue and (possibly) run at a later, undetermined time. Use the Dispose pattern if you need to clean up resources.

Comment: There is no guarantee as to when objects' finalizers will be called and in which order. It's entirely possible that the `Resource` object is getting garbage collected before the `Foo` object's finalizer has a chance to run.

Comment: @damien the terminology seems to be used interchangeably between msdn and if I recall correctly the c# spec. But they aren't Destructors in the 'classical' sense

Comment: @Abion47 I've `System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` in place to force cleanup the foo, resource is not null, I'm checking `Assert.IsNotNull(resource)` in my unit tests after and they are passing

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 can you please supply an answer using Dispose pattern.

Comment: Your unit test is irrelevant since you're keeping a reference to `resource` around within the test, and so it could *never* be collected in that scenario.

Comment: @ericlippert has an article on the terms https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/01/21/whats-the-difference-between-a-destructor-and-a-finalizer/

Comment: @user2727195 I'm not talking about when garbage collection will happen in general. I'm talking about during the garbage collection process itself. It's a nebulous miasma of confusion and mystery where a bunch of stuff goes in and nothing comes out and magic happens in the middle. This is why people suggest not using finalizers at all if you can help it, and using the `IDisposable` interface when at all possible, because it is far more reliable.

Comment: @user2727195 unless either object is holding on to resources that require Explicit clean up (streams, objects implementing `IDisposable`) there's isn't an immediate need to do anything. File handles are another example of an unmanaged resource I omitted from my first comment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's relevant in the sense that I'm using it to ensure all cyclic references between objects are resolved in my library when I remove the parent object, I've a bigger picture

Comment: @Abion47 ok, can you please provide an answer using Dispose pattern, I looked it up but it's confusing for me at the moment.

Comment: guys, see my edit please, I've added an if statement and now no more errors, don't know why, any ideas?

Comment: I cannot duplicate your results; indeed, as far as I can see, you shouldn't be getting a null reference exception.

Comment: Wait a minute: "**Unit Tests are passing** but I see NullReferenceException in the console" - so the code you posted doesn't actually duplicate the problem, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it does actually duplicate the problem, you can try it. Unit tests are passing but I see NullReferenceException in the console, and guess what if you see my edit, the if clause removed that error, doesn't make any sense to me, I highly encourage you to run this please.

Comment: I did try it, and it doesn't duplicate the problem on my system. No null reference exception. Although what you mean by "the console" is a little confusing; I assumed you meant the output window. Also you said "unit tests" plural, yet you only posted one unit test. What you're saying doesn't tally with the code you've posted.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes the output window shows the error, the only difference between my code and posted code is that class `Foo` has a parent class which I think shouldn't be a problem, so did you see any error message in the output window? I'm using visual studio 2017 RC enterprise. I've other tests but this test relates to the issue and has no dependency on other tests. for sure.

Comment: Nope, no errors. I suggest you post a complete and minimal repro. Create a new unit test project and put all the classes and unit test code into it (as few classes as possible to reproduce the error). The aim is to allow someone to copy/paste your code into a unit test project and run it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson no idea why, but would you be surprised to see that my edit section has the solution to the problem.

Comment: I can verify that the code as posted does not produce these errors. That being said, like I said before, the behavior of the GC is very unpredictable - do not depend on your object being garbage collected and your finalizer called at a particular time. As for your edit, that fix doesn't surprise me either. It likely has to do with compilation optimization - even if a reference to a local object is held, the GC can tell that it isn't going to be used again, so it marks it as collectible. The addition of the `if` marks a place where `Resource` will be needed, though, so it won't be.

Comment: It looks more like an instance of `Foo` is being created without a subsequent assignment to `Foo.Resource`; alternatively, some code is setting `Foo.Resource` to null before the finalizer is called. Either way, this is happening in code that does not exist in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your `Foo` class reimplemented with the `IDisposable` pattern:

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Resource.Release = true;
    }

    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do I've to call `Dispose()` manually or it's automatically called?

Comment: @user2727195 You need to call it manually, either explicitly by calling `fooObj.Dispose()` or implicitly with a `using` block. (You could also call it in `Foo`'s finalizer, but like I said before, that's not something that you can reliably depend on getting called at the "right time".)

Comment: You call it manually via `Dispose()` or by using the variable within a `using(...) {...} `block. But note that once out of scope of the using block, you have no access to the variable itself, nor to it's `Resource` property. So if you need to access it you'd have to manage the `Dispose` manually. Based on that and the usage you describe in the comments I am not sure that this pattern will aid you in what you are doing without a bunch of additional utility.

Comment: Thanks for giving an understanding about `Dispose`, I understand now and with that understanding, let me say more, actually resource object has several other properties indicating release for each object within the library, there are couple of actors who have cyclic dependencies, and I want to ensure they all get deallocated without my manual intervention of Dispose, that's why the destructor/finalize is in use of my example. is cyclic references really a problem for GC in csharp or can it detect?

Comment: @user2727195 - What made you think that cyclic references were an issue for the GC? Are you sure you're not just adding more work for yourself here for issues that don't actually exist?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever possibly, partly because I'm coming from objective-c, swift background and also because of presence of `WeakReference` type in csharp, and that's what I've used within one class in a pair of classes that has cyclic references and unit tests are to ensure that when I remove holder objects those cyclic objects should be garbage collected automatically. that's why I'm not going the route of dispose pattern.

Comment: @user2727195 If your objects make use of unmanaged resources, you should be using `IDisposable` to quickly and reliably release those resources as soon as possible. Otherwise, the GC is generally robust enough that you almost never need to worry about hand-holding the finalization like this.

Comment: @user2727195 Have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx and pay particular attention to the section entitled **What happens during a garbage collection**. Also have a read of https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/

Comment: "I want to ensure they all get deal located without my manual intervention of Dispose"... The problem is that Finalizers are not called deterministically.  What this means is that their order is not guaranteed. They could run out of sequence, seconds or even minutes apart. They aren't even guaranteed to be called at all. This bit a library I worked on at my old job. The original developer came from c++ and designed a lot of things around the destructor. Lots of errors/crashes and logging statements (in his finalizers) appeared inaccurate and out of order. We fixed it by implementing dispose.